# Android find resource by id during the runtime

Tags: android, resources

If I get the error "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050007 type #0x12 is not valid" can I find some what this resource is if I know its ID?

```
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.messages_list_view);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
        R.layout.messages_list, headers));
```

messages_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/messages_list_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/messages_list_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You mean that you do not use R.id? Could you hint me why?

Comment: without knowing what you have you tried to implement, how can we suggest?

Comment: You surely set proper layout for your activity?

Comment: Just a hint: Use @id/android:list for your ListView. Look here --> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the search function in eclipse, search for `"0x7f050007"` or go to `projectfolder/gen/path/R.java` that contains your resources.

You'll find something like this:

```
public static final int lineItem=0x7f07001c;
```

Then search for(in this example) `lineItem` with Eclipses search function. It'll take you to your resource in code.

Answer (score 5):

I Got this error when using ListView in a Fragment.

Resolved by moving the setAdapter lines to the onViewCreated function of the Fragment. (makes sense that before the view is created the ListView is invalid).

so you get :

```
public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ListView list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.thelist);
    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For those whom other mentioned solutions don't work.

I did this silly mistake:-

```
setContentView(R.id.something);
```

Instead of

```
setContentView(R.layout.something);
```

Corrected that, and error was gone :D

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports (at the top of your class-file). Maybe you imported

```
android.R
```

(which provides access to the platform-resources) instead of

```
{your_package_name}.R
```

(you can also leave it blank).